# One column of Azure SQL database appears sorted

Tags: sql, azure, pyodbc

I have a SQL database in Azure as seen in the link below. I'm making an applet in python using pyodbc to update the Elos of the people in the database. I made three connection objects (one for each of the columns seen), and used a while loop to iterate through.

It'll take an input from the user, iterate until it finds the ID code entered, and since all the cursors are in the same while loop the Rating and Name cursors will always be in the same row.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZssyW.png

Except for some reason, the ID column is sorted. The table on the left is a screenshot from Microsoft Sql Server Management Server, and the one on the right is what happens when the three cursors iterate through and print each time.

How do I fix this/what's causing this?

Here's (the relevant part of) my code:

```
current_id = (ID_cursor.execute("SELECT LocalID FROM MEMBERS"))
current_rating = (rating_cursor.execute("SELECT Rating FROM MEMBERS"))
current_firstname = (firstname_cursor.execute("SELECT FirstName FROM MEMBERS"))

counter = 0
while counter < 10:
    counter += 1
    temp_id = ID_cursor.fetchone()[0]
    temp_rating = rating_cursor.fetchone()[0]
    temp_firstname = firstname_cursor.fetchone()[0]

    print(temp_id, temp_firstname, temp_rating)

print("end")
```

Comment: Why don't you just `ORDER BY` the queries with the column you want?

Comment: How would I do that? I can't order the Ratings or names, each row has to stay with itself (each ID has to match a specific name/rating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply an `ORDER BY` clause to all three queries so they are sorted the same way. I'm assuming `LocalID` is your primary key identity column?

```
current_id = (ID_cursor.execute("SELECT LocalID FROM MEMBERS ORDER BY LocalID"))
current_rating = (rating_cursor.execute("SELECT Rating FROM MEMBERS ORDER BY LocalID"))
current_firstname = (firstname_cursor.execute("SELECT FirstName FROM MEMBERS ORDER BY LocalID"))
```

Without an `ORDER BY` clause specified, SQL Server may order by the column in the `SELECT` statement.